# What's the output object file format of GNU assembler as?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gnu, gnu-assembler

I have checked the assembler options of **GNU assembler as** and I didn't find an option to specify the output object file format. If I am using the following command

```
as -o foobar.o foobar.s
```

What object file format will I get?

The as manual says that "*The GNU as can be configured to produce several alternative object file formats.*" But how?  How can I change it to a ELF format?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux the output from gas is ELF already, it is unlikely you have a version which is building the old a.out format, or that you are using a cross compiler to say build to MachO or PE.

Comment: Thanks tyranid. I noticed that I can specify differnt object file formats when using the "NASM" assembler. It seems the GNU "as" is not as good as NASM in this aspect. I have to use the "objcopy" to change the object file format. Is there some more direct approach with the "as"?

Comment: I don't think you can do directly, you would always have to use objcopy.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a cross-compiler for specific formats (ARM,MIPS etc.)

Get the entire CODESOURCERY toolchain here for free:

> www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite_edition.html

GoodLUCK!!

Comment: Thansk CVS26. I am not making a cross compiling. I386 is my target. I will give it a try, if i am desperate enough...